# SELECT count not working after added join

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, join, count

I have this query:

```
select Keyword, Keywords.QuoteId, count(*) AS TotalTags 
from [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Keywords 
join [QuotesTemple].[dbo].QuoteImages 
ON QuoteImages.QuoteId=Keywords.QuoteId
group by Keyword, Keywords.QuoteId
```

The query works, except the TotalTags is always 1, before I have added the join it worked.

For a keyword which should have TotalTags=5 it displays the keyword 5 times with count 1.

If I remove the `Keywords.QuoteId` from group the query returns an error.

Comment: . . Please show the query that returns the results you expect.

Comment: select Keyword, count(*) from Keywords group by Keyword

Comment: and now I have added the join to show only the keywords which have a quote which has an image.

Comment: I think the group is not working, because it shows each keyword more times. For a keyword which should have TotalTags=5 it displays the keyword 5 times with count 1

Comment: @MarioM Show table structures and desired results please

Comment: You are grouping by two columns, so it must be that you have 5 different quoteID for that keyword. Why have you added quoteID to the group by clause?

Comment: I have added quoteid, because I got an error if I did not add it.

Comment: @MarioM you got an error because you added `QuoteID` to the `SELECT` list. Why did you do that? Do you want to see a `QuoteID` value in the output? If a keyword has 5 quotes, which one do you want to see?

Comment: because with my query, and no quoteid added to group by, I got this error: Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Column 'QuotesTemple.dbo.Keywords.QuoteId' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: Yes I understand that, but again, why did you add QuoteId to the select list? The error only appeared after you did that. *shrug* You're talking circles around yourself.

Comment: Because I got another error with ambigous QuoteId (it is contained in 2 different tables) and then I have specified the database name in JOIN and I forgot about the select.

Comment: Wow. I should have left this question alone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this work?

```
select Keyword, count(QuoteImages.QuoteId) AS TotalTags 
from [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Keywords 
join [QuotesTemple].[dbo].QuoteImages 
ON QuoteImages.QuoteId=Keywords.QuoteId
group by Keyword
```

As @Nenad pointed out, it's probably QuoteId that caused the problem. You don't want to see a separate result for each QuoteId.

Answer (score 1):

You've added an additional column to your grouping, so if you have 5 unique quotes for any keyword, of course the count for each combination will be 1. Try:

```
select k.Keyword, k.QuoteId, 
  count(*) OVER (PARTITION BY k.Keyword) AS TotalTags 
from [enter_your_database_name_here].[dbo].Keywords AS k
INNER JOIN [enter_your_database_name_here].[dbo].QuoteImages AS q
ON k.QuoteId = q.QuoteId
group by k.Keyword, k.QuoteId;
```

If you don't want to see a row for each `QuoteId`, then take it out of both the `SELECT` list and the `GROUP BY`. You might also not care about the join at all, why not gamble to maybe get slightly better performance (or, at worst, the same):

```
SELECT k.Keyword, COUNT(*) AS TotalTags
FROM [enter_your_database_name_here_if_you_want_to
  run_from_another_database_for_some_reason].dbo.Keywords AS k
WHERE EXISTS
(
  SELECT 1 FROM [enter_your_database_name_here_if_you_want_to
  run_from_another_database_for_some_reason].dbo.QuoteImages
  WHERE QuoteID = k.QuoteID
)
GROUP BY k.Keyword;
```

If you don't care about the individual Quotes then I have no idea why you added . You say you got an error, but is this because you added it only to the SELECT list or only to the GROUP BY list? Why would you introduce it to either list?

Comment: Msg 208, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
Invalid object name 'dbo.Keywords'.

Comment: @MarioM well, you told us the table names. Did you try running this query from the right database (`[QuotesTemple]`)? Otherwise please add the database prefixes there yourself.

Comment: yes, your second solution works, but it's much slower compared to the query I choosed as the answer. This query took 1 second and the other one 0.1s because this have 2 times select

Comment: Sorry, I don't know what you mean by "this have 2 times select"...

Comment: You had a select in another select which is time consuming

Comment: An EXISTS is not a "select within a select" but believe whatever you want.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when you replace the `join` with a `left outer join`:

```
select Keyword, Keywords.QuoteId, count(*) AS TotalTags 
from [QuotesTemple].[dbo].Keywords 
left outer join [QuotesTemple].[dbo].QuoteImages 
ON QuoteImages.QuoteId=Keywords.QuoteId
group by Keyword, Keywords.QuoteId
```

I can think of two things.  One is that you also added `keywords.QuoteId` when you added the join.  And there is one tag per quote.

The other is that there is a quote on only some of the keywords.

Comment: Some of the tags have more keywords, so it should not be 1 for all the results.

Comment: with left outter join I get inverse results which I don't need, and the count is still 1